# Background-coloring a specific TD inside a table with PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have a code that generates a table.

```
while ($i <= 30) {


        echo "<tr id=\"Row{$i}\">";
        while ($d <= 90) {
            $d = $d + 1;
            echo '<td id="C' . $i .''. $d . '">'.$i.''.$d.';</td>';
        }
        $d = 0;

        echo '</tr>';
         $i = $i + 1;
    }
```

As you can see I've given each table cell a unique ID. Now, I want to be able to target that ID for a certain table-cell further down in the code and say give it a background-color: yellow;

How do I do that? Because If I echo  it will create a new table cell instead of hitting hte already existing one. Would like help. Thank you.

Comment: you want to do this with php ? or you can use javascript ?

Comment: your requirement is not clear, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: you can always use inline css... But as is stated, your requirement is not to clear...

Comment: Read my comment in the answer below to understand what I want to create.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a string variable with id value you need to target for background-color

Comment: I did set it. But how do I echo the style?

Comment: You can use cookies or session too to set value of your custom id and via jQuery set the background with selector pointing to your element, but it's not better and most perfomant way. Infact, it's better to set background directly in your php while cicle, adding the case you have to set background color. There you must add css class to your td

Answer (score 0):

if you know the row and column number for this specific cell let's say row 3 cell 45 then you can proceed like this

```
while ($i <= 30) {

    echo "<tr id=\"Row{$i}\">";
    while ($d <= 90) {
        if($i == 3 && $d== 45)
        {
          $d = $d + 1;
          echo '<td class =\'yourclass\' id="C' . $i .''. $d . '">'.$i.''.$d.';</td>';
        }
        else 
        {
        $d = $d + 1;
        echo '<td id="C' . $i .''. $d . '">'.$i.''.$d.';</td>';
        }
    }
    $d = 0;

    echo '</tr>';
     $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Basically what I wanted to create is a script for testing my PHP. I had an idea to create a script that will ask for a name. Once you enter a name it will generate a table that has certain cells colored in a form of a letter. That's why I need it colored later. But I guess I can do it while creating it in the first place just have to figure out new approach =\. That is if there is no way to style already created table.

Comment: it's a bit hard to color such based table because for each letter you must know the needed cells information ( row and column ) , a close approach is to store all the letters as keys along with their row number and column number , then color each letter of the name entered according to its row and column number stored into the array mentioned

Comment: I'm kinda figuring that out. Yeah I'm gonna parse the word someone enters into a single one letter strings. Then based on that string I will create a script that will check what letter it is and then when it hits to move in a certain table-cell (dependent on letter) and color the table-cells. Some letters will be easy such as I for example. But I still need to color the td somehow... And I'm honestly surprised there is no way to style it once created.